# SignalR Send Message from view to a Hub

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I'm writing application which use SignalR to send Messages from hub to view, I'm asking is there a possible way that view can send message back to the Hub , is this possible and if possible how to do that ?!

My application use SignalR to Uploadfiles and it works fine, user can press cancel Upload, I need to deliver this message to hub so it will be easy to cancel upload.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ask for a concept not a problem in my code, my code works fine , I updated my question so you can get the whole point, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a conceptual example, your implementation will probably look different.

JavaScript (assign an onclick event to cancel button, and run following code):

```
var serverConnection = new $.connection("/example"); //<-- ref app.MapSignalR<YourClass>("/example");

serverConnection.start(function () {

    serverConnection.send("upload_canceled")
});
```

C#

```
protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
    if(data == "upload_canceled")
    {
        //Do something in response to user canceled upload
    }
}
```